# how to create Maven dependencies bat file?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a pom file where i have added all the dependencies. and .m2 folder where i have added Jar files added

But i am looking for a file where i can just add all the dependencies in the file like and run it.

> mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:get
>   -DrepoUrl=http://download.java.net/maven/2/ -Dartifact=robo-guice:robo-guice:0.4-SNAPSHOT

So that i don't have to worry about jar files in my .m2 folder.

Is there any way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Comment: look at [Vijay's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3770791/42126), which uses the shade plugin rather than the assembly plugin

Comment: http://mojo.codehaus.org/appassembler/appassembler-maven-plugin/ might be solution or the http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` to copy all dependencies to some folder.

The other solution is to create a single JAR which contains everything. See the answers to this question: [How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)